# Using DatePicker with Form FormItem in antd design react

Tags: reactjs, antd

```
    <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="Publish Date">
      {getFieldDecorator('publishDate', {
        initialValue: '',
        rules: [
          {
            required: false,
            message: 'Please input publishDate',
            whitespace: true,
          },
        ],
      })(<DatePicker onChange={onChange} />)}
    </FormItem>
```

doesn't work.  I get async validator saying 'publishDate is not a string'.

so I'm using it this way as a temporary solution.

```
<FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="Publish Date">
  {getFieldDecorator('publishDate', {
    initialValue: getCurrentDate(),
    rules: [
      {
        required: false,
        message: 'Please input publishDate',
        whitespace: true,
      },
    ],
  })}
  <DatePicker onChange={onChange} />
</FormItem>
```

any help ? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

should be using `type: 'object'` in rules

```
<FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="Publish Date">
  {getFieldDecorator('publishDate', {
    initialValue: moment(),
    rules: [
      {
        type: 'object',
        required: false,
        message: 'Please input publishDate',
        whitespace: true,
      },
    ],
  })(<DatePicker/>)}
</FormItem>
```

Also, you wouldn't need `onChange` handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Form.Item
            name={"name"}
            label="Toll Name"
            rules={[
              {
                required: true,
                message: "toll name required",
              },
              {
                validator: (_, value) =>
                  !value.endsWith(" ") 
                    ? Promise.resolve()
                    : Promise.reject(new Error("No spaces allowed")),
              },
            ]}
         >
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>
```

Comment: this question is about using DatePicker of antd in Form

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
const makeDateField = Component => ({
  input,
  meta,
  children,
  hasFeedback,
  label,
  labelRight,
  ...rest
}) => {
  /* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
  const hasError = meta.touched && meta.invalid;

  input = {
    ...input,
    value: input.value && input.value._isValid ? moment(input.value) : moment(),

  };
  return (
    <FormItem
      {...formItemLayout}
      label={label}
      validateStatus={hasError ? 'error' : 'success'}
      hasFeedback={hasFeedback && hasError}
      help={hasError && meta.error}
    >
      <Component 
        {...input} 
        {...rest}
        onChange={(event, value) => input.onChange(event)} 
        onBlur={(event, value) => input.onBlur(value) } 
      >
        {children}
      </Component>
      {labelRight && <span style={{ color: '#9e9e9e' }}>{labelRight}</span>}
    </FormItem>
  );
};

export const ADatePicker = makeDateField(DatePicker);
```

Usage in form

```
   <Field
     label="Start Date"
     placeholder="Start Date"
     name="startDate"
     component={ADatePicker}
   />
```