# Properly setting Antd DatePicker initial value using getFieldDecorator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Trying to set default field value to **antd** `Datepicker` using `getFieldDecorator` two-way binding.

`form.getFieldValue('joiningDate')` is a timestamp value

1st try

```
<Form.Item >
  {getFieldDecorator('joiningDate', { initialValue: moment.unix(form.getFieldValue('joiningDate')) })(
   <DatePicker disabled={inProgress}></DatePicker>
  )}
</Form.Item>
```

2nd try

```
<Form.Item >
  {getFieldDecorator('joiningDate', { initialValue: moment()) })(
   <DatePicker  disabled={inProgress}></DatePicker>
  )}
</Form.Item>
```

Both the above method throws following error when `joiningDate` has a value -

[image]

If `joiningDate` is null there is no error and using 2nd method by default it should display today's date.

Update:

If I precreate moment object of `joiningDate`, then `DatePicker` works. But I want to format it only at the time of binding to Datepicker. Seems the `initialValue` prop has no effect.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <FlexBox>
      <FormContainer data={{ joiningDate: Date.now() }} />
    </FlexBox>
  );
}
const MyForm = ({ form }) => {
  const { getFieldDecorator } = form;
  return (
    <Form>
      <Form.Item>
        {getFieldDecorator("joiningDate", { initialValue: moment() })(
          <DatePicker />
        )}
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

const FormContainer = Form.create({
  name: "advanced_search",
  mapPropsToFields({ data }) {
    if (!data) return;
    let precreatedFields = {
      joiningDate: Form.createFormField({
        value: data["joiningDate"]
      })
    };

    //more fields are removed
    return precreatedFields;
  }
})(MyForm);
```

Code [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-antd-react-starter-hvb4o?fontsize=14)

*NB: Similar question([Using DatePicker with Form FormItem in antd design react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49841281/using-datepicker-with-form-formitem-in-antd-design-react)). It had different error "I get async validator saying 'publishDate is not a string"*

Comment: You need to show `{...inputProperties['joiningDate']}` which causes the error, please create a **reproducible** example, refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DennisVash updated code sample. `inputProperties` contains only placeholder values which is not related to what error is shown. In the official documentation if I'm using `getFieldDecorator`, `defaultValue` or `value` properties shouldnot be used. So you shouldn't assume that this `{...inputProperties['joiningDate']}` will have anything that would cause the error stated.

Comment: Try adding a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/antdstart-n8n96, the 2nd try should work, still without a good **reproducible** example, it hard to help you.

Comment: @DennisVash thats the problem DatePicker.

Comment: Thats not, as you can see I edited your sandbox and it works

Comment: This is form is not only for adding new value but for editing also. I will get `joiningDate` from api which should also be editable . The actual situation is https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-antd-react-starter-hvb4o?fontsize=14. The antd throws the error shown in screenshot which is not shown in sandbox due to CORS policy.The first decorator was to test if it works with input type. The second is what I need.

Comment: Please read again - [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), make a **Reproducible** example, in YOUR CASE make a MOCK data that will simulate your problem, it is essential for people in order to help you, the problem may be in how you HANDLING the data from API.

Comment: please look into mock again. I just had one Input component extra

Comment: It doesn't matter, you using `data` as props, but you not showing how you passing this data to your form or how it looks like.

Comment: That's literally the code I'm using and the data is actually the same object with only `joiningDate`. Do you see the mapPropsToField? It was there from starting which you have removed in your sandbox example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initializing `datePicker` not with a `moment` instance.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <FlexBox>
//                                        v Not `Date.now()`
      <FormContainer data={{ joiningDate: moment() }} />
    </FlexBox>
  );
}
```

Thats why you get a runtime error on `mapPropsToFields`:

```
const FormContainer = Form.create({
  name: 'advanced_search',
  mapPropsToFields({ data }) {
    if (!data) return;
    let precreatedFields = {
      joiningDate: Form.createFormField({
        value: data['joiningDate']
      })
    };

//          v You initializing 'joiningDate' with Date.now() and not with moment.
    return precreatedFields;
  }
})(MyForm);
```

[image: Edit Q-57986729-FixDatePicker]

Comment: Thanks. I think `initialValue` is useless if I set the form data values using `mapPropsToFields`.

Comment: It's not useless when `!data === true`

Comment: Nice, feel free accepting answer if it was helpful, please make a producible example next time, cheers